# Field wise form validation

Tags: javascript, html

On submitting an empty form I'm receiving the respective errors but I want to remove the error (when they meet the requirement) as I proceed to the next input. Also can anyone give me a solution to do the same with the help of loops. Only JavaScript solution please.

Here's my JS and HTML code..

```js
 function validate() {
  var letter = /[a-zA-Z]/;
  var number = /[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}/;
  var mail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
  var valid = true;

  var firstname = information.first.value;
  var lastname = information.last.value;
  var address = information.Add.value;
  var email = information.Email.value;
  var pass = information.Pass.value;
  var re_pass = information.Repass.value;
  var phone = information.mobile.value;


  if (firstname === "" || !letter.test(firstname)) {
    document.getElementById("fn").innerHTML = "*Enter your First Name*";
    console.log("first");
    valid = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("fn").innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (lastname === "" || !letter.test(lastname)) {
    document.getElementById("ln").innerHTML = "*Enter your Last Name*";
    console.log("last");
    valid = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("ln").innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (email === "" || !mail.test(email)) {
    document.getElementById("mail").innerHTML = "*Enter your Email*";
    console.log("mail");
    valid = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("mail").innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (pass === "" || !letter.test(Pass)) {
    document.getElementById("pwd").innerHTML = "*Enter your Password*";

    console.log("password");
    valid = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("pwd").innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (re_pass === "" || re_pass != pass) {
    document.getElementById("repass").innerHTML = "*Password didn't match*";
    console.log("reenter");
    valid = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("repass").innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (phone == "" || !number.test(phone)) {
    document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = "*Enter your Phone number";
    console.log("phone");
    valid = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = "";
  } 
  return valid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>information</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="info.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="info.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="form">
    <form action="#" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()" name="information">
      <label>Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your name" id="first" autofocus>
      <span id="fn"></span><br><br>
      <label>Lastname:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter last name" id="last">
      <span id="ln"></span><br><br>
      <label>Address:</label>
      <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" id="Add">
      <span id="add"></span><br><br>
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email" id="Email">
      <span id="mail"></span><br><br>
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="Pass">
      <span id="pwd"></span><br><br>
      <label>Retype Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="retype" placeholder="Retype password" id="Repass">
      <span id="repass"></span><br><br>
      <label>Phone:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXX" id="mobile" maxlength = "10">
      <span id="no"></span><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add your validate to oninput of the fields

Comment: Also never call anything "submit" in a form - if you ever want to submit by script you will not be able to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```js
var letter = /[a-zA-Z]/;
var number = /[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}/;
var mail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;


function validate() {
  var information = document.querySelector("#form>form");
  var error = 0;

  var firstname = information.first.value;
  var lastname = information.last.value;
  var address = information.Add.value;
  var email = information.Email.value;
  var pass = information.Pass.value;
  var re_pass = information.Repass.value;
  var phone = information.mobile.value;


  error += firstname === "" || !letter.test(firstname)
  document.getElementById("fn").innerHTML = error?"*Enter your First Name*":"";


  error += lastname === "" || !letter.test(lastname)
  document.getElementById("ln").innerHTML = error?"*Enter your Last Name*":"";

  error += email === "" || !mail.test(email)
  document.getElementById("mail").innerHTML = error?"*Enter your Email*":"";

  error += pass === "" || !letter.test(Pass)
  document.getElementById("pwd").innerHTML = error?"*Enter your Password*":"";

  error += re_pass === "" || re_pass !== pass
  document.getElementById("repass").innerHTML = error?"*Password didn't match*":"";

  error += phone === "" || !number.test(phone)
  document.getElementById("no").innerHTML = error ? "*Enter your Phone number":"";

  return error>0?false:true;
}
document.querySelector("#form>form").oninput = validate;
document.querySelector("#form>form").onsubmit = validate;
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <form action="#" method="POST" name="information">
    <label>Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your name" id="first" autofocus>
    <span id="fn"></span><br><br>
    <label>Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter last name" id="last">
    <span id="ln"></span><br><br>
    <label>Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" id="Add">
    <span id="add"></span><br><br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="Email" id="Email">
    <span id="mail"></span><br><br>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="Pass">
    <span id="pwd"></span><br><br>
    <label>Retype Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="retype" placeholder="Retype password" id="Repass">
    <span id="repass"></span><br><br>
    <label>Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="XXXXXXXXXX" id="mobile" maxlength="10">
    <span id="no"></span><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It's doing the job but see on submitting empty form it is showing error to the first input only and while proceeding further it is showing error as an instruction.......  but it worked fine when i used oninput for respective text box.